# if in_array AND array_intersect not working inside foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

What I'm trying to do is take the user's zipcode and see if it exists inside of one of the arrays inside the $zipcodes foreach statement.

If the users' zip exists in any of the $zipcode arrays, then we need to show the users' ZIP and what $key their ZIP exists in.

example $key: `Atlanta`

example $value (shortened, 348 results): `["30002","30003","30004","30005","30006","30007"]`

doing a var_dump of $value results in:
`array(348) { [0]=> string(5) "30002" [1]=> string(5) "30003" [2]=> string(5) "30004" [3]=> string(5) "30005" [4]=> string(5) "30006" [5]=> string(5) "30007" }`

example user zipcode:
`30004`

I've tried both in_array and array_intersect, neither seem to be working.

```
function display_zipcodes_raw() {

    $zipcodes = [];
    // For each territory - if user ZIP is in the array
    foreach (get_territories() as $territory) {
        $zipcodes[$territory['name']] = array_column( get_zipcodes( $territory['id'] ), 'zip_code' );
        
        $users_zipcode = CFGP_U::api('postcode');
        $needle = array($users_zipcode);

        foreach ($zipcodes as $key => $value) {
            /*$stack = array_intersect($needle,$value);
            if (in_array($users_zipcode, $value, TRUE)) {
                $results = ' key: ' . $key . '<br>value: '.json_encode($value);
            }*/
            if (in_array($users_zipcode, $value, TRUE)) {
                $results = ' key: ' . $key . '<br>value: '.json_encode($value);
            }
        }

        echo 'key: '.$key.'<br>';
        echo 'value: '.json_encode($value).'<br>';
    }

    return 'User ZIP: '.$users_zipcode.'<br>';
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have nested loops. Use one loop to fill in `$zipcodes`, and then another loop to search it.

Comment: Why are you returning `json_encode($value)`? That's the array of all zipcodes in the territory. Do you really need that?

Comment: This [mcve] has too many variables that we don't have sample data for.  Please help us to set up a reproducible example.  If the code prior to the inner loop is working, then remove the outer loop from your question and give us a single iteration's data.  Then you can offer static sample data and show us how the inner loop is not working properly.  What is the data type of `$users_zipcode`, what is the data type of `$value`? Is this a problem with `in_array()` using `true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for the `$zipcodes` array. Just search the result of `array_column( get_zipcodes( $territory['id'] ), 'zip_code' )` each time through the loop.

```
function display_zipcodes_raw() {
    $users_zipcode = CFGP_U::api('postcode');
    foreach (get_territories() as $territory) {
        $zipcodes = array_column( get_zipcodes( $territory['id'] ), 'zip_code' );
        if (in_array($users_zipcode, $zipcodes, TRUE)) {
            return "User ZIP: $users_zipcode<br>Territory: {$territory['name']}<br>";
        }
    }

    return "User ZIP: $users_zipcode<br> not found: <br>";

}
```

Comment: this returns 'not found' still.

Comment: Sorry, I had a copying error and left out `array_column`

Comment: even after the fix it's still showing 'not found'

Comment: Is `$users_zipcode` a string or a number? The `TRUE` argument to `in_array()` makes the comparison strict, so it won't match if it's a number.

Comment: $users_zipcode is a string

Comment: Then I can't think of a reason why it's not working, unless the zip code is in a territory that `get_territories()` doesn't return.

Comment: I'm a bit late here, but removing true fixed the issue. Thanks again.